# Determine amount of time remaining on method that times out

Tags: java, timeout, locking, contract

I am trying to write a lock class to help with situations where I need to be able to prioritize various thread's acccess to a synchronized resource, but I have run into an issue with meeting the contract for `Lock::tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)`.

My current method is this:

```
@Override
public boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
    if(super.tryLock(time, unit)) //my class extends `ReentrantLock`
        if(next.tryLock(time, unit))
            return true;
        else
            super.unlock();
    return false;
}
```

While at first glance, this doesn't seem wrong, the issue is that the method, by contract, must time out after `time` `unit`s, while this method could potentially take up to twice that.

In order to do that, I need to be able to figure out how much of the time was taken by `super.tryLock`, and then only give `next.tryLock` the amount of time left over.

I considered using a `Timer` with a `TimerTask` that decrements `time` each `TimeUnit`:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
                //Decrement time somehow
        }
    },
    0, unit.toMillis(1));
```

However, this won't work for units smaller than a millisecond, it might take as much as one more unit than specified (which, for all we know, might be `TimeUnit.DAYS`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just measuring the elapsed time with `System.nanoTime()` and subtracting it from the time remaining; 292 years is almost certainly longer than any thread that uses `tryLock` is going to wait (or even still exist, for that matter).

```
@Override
public boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    if(super.tryLock(time, unit)){

        time -= unit.convert(System.nanoTime() - start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        if(next.tryLock(time, unit))
            return true;
        else
            super.unlock();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Although I will probably end up using this, I would like to at least know what I would want to do to be able to meet the contract exactly, not just well beyond the edges of any reasonable use case.